# Breaking out an each iteration if false but return true in other case ruby

Tags: ruby, each, break

I have this basic issue, I want my function to return true if the input strings are a permutation, and false otherwise. I have a very ugly solution and I would prefer to do something like this:

```
def permutation?(a, b)
  p chars_a = a.split('').group_by { |char| char }
  p chars_b = b.split('').group_by { |char| char }
  chars_a. each do |k, v|
    break false unless (chars_b.key?(k) && chars_b[k].count == v.count)
  end
end
```

The problem is when I run the tests the function doesn't return true when it is. It's a  basic syntax problem I guess.. Can you help?

The ugly solution :

```
def permutation?(a, b)
  p chars_a = a.split('').group_by { |char| char }
  p chars_b = b.split('').group_by { |char| char }
  sorry = []
  chars_a. each do |k, v|
    if b = chars_b.key?(k) && chars_b[k].count == v.count
      b = true
    else
      b = false
    end
    sorry << b
  end
  if sorry.include?(false)
     false
  else
    true
  end
end
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying? What are the input values you're using and the expected output?

Comment: You need to clarify the problem you are trying to solve, and improve the title. One or two examples (that included the desired return value) would be helpful, but that is no substitute for a clear statement of the problem in words.

Answer (score 1):

The `each` method returns its receiver—i.e. the object you called it on—so your `permutation?` method is returning `false` when you `break` and `chars_a` otherwise.

There are lots of ways you could solve this. You could create a variable outside the block and set it to `true` or `false`, then return the variable at the end of the method:

```
def permutation?(a, b)
  chars_a = a.chars.group_by {|char| char }
  chars_b = b.chars.group_by {|char| char }

  result = true
  chars_a.each do |k, v|
    unless chars_b.key?(k) && chars_b[k].size == v.size
      result = false
      break
    end
  end

  result
end
```

You could also use `return false` instead of `break false` inside the block, and then return `true` otherwise:

```
def permutation?(a, b)
  chars_a = a.chars.group_by {|char| char }
  chars_b = b.chars.group_by {|char| char }

  chars_a.each do |k, v|
    return false unless chars_b.key?(k) && chars_b[k].size == v.size
  end

  true
end
```

Neither of these is very Rubyish, though. A more idiomatic solution would be to replace `each` with a method that returns `true` or `false`. In this [`all?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) is a perfect fit. It returns `true` if the block evaluates to a truthy value for every item, and `false` otherwise:

```
def permutation?(a, b)
  chars_a = a.chars.group_by {|char| char }
  chars_b = b.chars.group_by {|char| char }

  chars_a.all? do |k, v|
    chars_b.key?(k) && chars_b[k].size == v.size
  end
end
```

However, there's an error in your logic. Your method checks if `b` contains all of the characters of `a`, but not the other way around.

```
permutation?("antler", "rentals")
# => true

permutation?("rentals", "antler")
# => false
```

That's because you check if `b` contains all of the characters of `a`, but not the other around. An easy fix is to make it bail out early if the inputs aren't the same size:

```
def permutation?(a, b)
  return false unless a.size == b.size

  chars_a = a.chars.group_by {|char| char }
  chars_b = b.chars.group_by {|char| char }

  chars_a.all? do |k, v|
    chars_b.key?(k) && chars_b[k].size == v.size
  end
end
```

Although a more succinct—but slower—solution would be to just check if `chars_a` and `chars_b` have the same keys and values, which Ruby makes very easy:

```
def permutation?(a, b)
  a.chars.group_by {|char| char } === b.chars.group_by {|char| char }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for guiding me to the most rubyish way to solve the basic problem. I love this language even more!

Comment: Glad to help! If my answer solved your problem feel free to mark it as accepted and/or give it an upvote. :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that, given two strings, you wish to determine if the characters of the second are a permutation of the characters of the first, and vice-versa. If so, that can be done quite easily.

```
def permutation?(str1, str2)
  str1.chars.sort == str2.chars.sort
end
```

```
permutation?('abc', 'cab')   #=> true
permutation?('aba', 'baa')   #=> true
permutation?('abc', 'caba')  #=> false
permutation?('', '')         #=> true
```

This is another way that can be done:

```
def permutation?(str1, str2)
  hashify(str1) == hashify(str2)
end

def hashify(str)
  str.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1 }
end
```

Note that:

```
h1 = hashify('aba')     #=> {"a"=>2, "b"=>1} 
h2 = hashify('baa')     #=> {"b"=>1, "a"=>2} 
h1 == h2                #=> true
```

See [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-c-new), specifically the (second) form that takes an argument (here zero) equal to the *default value*. All that means is that if a hash that had been defined `h = Hash.new(0)` has no key `k`, `h[k]` will return `0`. For reasons explained below, this is sometimes called a *counting hash*.

Ruby parses the expression `h[k] += 1` to:

```
h[k] = h[k] + 1
```

If `h` has no key `k`, `h[k]` on the right will return `0`, so `h[k]` will be set equal to `1`. Thereafter, for that key `k`, `h[k]` on the right will have a positive value which will be incremented by `1`.